# How to bind event for Canvas content?

Tags: python, events, button, canvas, tkinter

I have `Canvas` panel with gradient background color, and i want to add there some buttons with png images. Using canvas is only one solution to make good transparent textured buttons. I am using `create_image` method but it returns int and i cant bind event to it. How can i `bind` event to `Canvas` content?

```
self.tab = tk.Canvas(width=xc,height=yc,bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
self.tab.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
bg = self.tab.create_image(xc/2, yc/2, image=self.toolbar_image)
```

For example i need to `bind` event to `bg`. I can't `bind` event to `Canvas` because in future there will be more buttons which i need to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas does this with tags:

```
tab.create_image(x, y, image=img, tags='item')
tab.tag_bind('item', '<Button-1>', click)
```